# Creating unique instances in spring mvc 3 parent Controller

Tags: java, performance, spring-mvc, design-patterns

I'm developing a web app using the Spring 3 framework.
So, I have the next hierachy level in my controllers package:

```
@Controller
public class BaseController {

@Autowired
@Qualifier("problemService")
protected  ProblemService problemservice;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("codeService")
protected  CodeService codeservice;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("userService")
protected  UserService userservice;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("sessionRegistry")
protected  SessionRegistry session;
.....
}
```

with children

```
@Controller
public class CodeController extends BaseController{
...
}

@Controller
public class ProblemController extends BaseController{
...
}
```

What i want is all these service of BaseController available to the children, but more like static resources, that is, all children share an unique instance of the father's services, and not a new instance of each as inheritance does.
In that way, I tried this for each resource in BaseController:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("problemService")
protected static ProblemService problemservice;
```

but Spring throws a NullPointerException.
So, is my idea at least correct? I mean, i do want to do what i said, but i dont know if it is a good approach at least.

Comment: Don't use static members - as they introduce "global state" in a multi threaded environement. Using spring bean creation in default mode injects Singleton instances - that means for all concrete controllers the same instance of the 4 services is injected.

Comment: Any specific reason why it need to be static and not singleton injected by spring?

Comment: @fateddy: tnks a lot, so the singleton scope is the default one isn't?